# Could someone give an example to illustrate a decisions surface of naïve Bayes classifiers in 3d space with corresponding dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

The lecturer is [talking about](https://youtu.be/Mq0UpzWMe_o?t=901) decisions surface of naïve Bayes classifiers without giving an answer.

I [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=na%C3%AFve%20Bayes%20classifiers%203d&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ACYBGNSL-a_lNEZt6-2N1Mx-mmJMaUUrnQ:1573217235328&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr-tzz0trlAhVSPnAKHQleCmwQ_AUIEigB&biw=1264&bih=654) a lot and didn't find an example that illustrates a decisions surface of naïve Bayes classifiers in 3d space with corresponding dataset.

Could someone give such an example?